# Error installing Last Value Cache pluggable exchange

Tags: erlang, makefile, rabbitmq

I am trying to install the LVC exchange to my RabbitMQ broker.  I downloaded the public umbrella and ran make  as per the [instructions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html) on the RabbitMQ website.

Next I downloaded the LVC pluggin and followed their [instructions](https://github.com/squaremo/rabbitmq-lvc-plugin). However make didn't work so I am unable to continue.  Has anyone managed to install it, if so please can you give me full directions, from the very beginning.  Otherwise if anyone one has any ideas as to what I am doing wrong then please let me know.  Below is the output from make.

> ERL_LIBS=./build/dep-apps erlc -Wall +debug_info -I ./include -pa ebin -o ebin  src/rabbit_exchange_type_lvc.erl
>   src/rabbit_exchange_type_lvc.erl:11: can't find include lib "rabbit_common/include/rabbit_exchange_type_spec.hrl"
>   make: *** [ebin/rabbit_exchange_type_lvc.beam] Error 1

I have the same problem trying to install the [Recent History Exchange](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmq-recent-history-exchange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to this to remove the include line about rabbit_exchange_type_spec.  I found this information [here](https://github.com/simonmacmullen/random-exchange/commit/e6926f4edd0eceb6b0db3d10c110e458054e0063).  Tried it and and ran make again.  The make finished and I was able to enable the plugin after moving it to the correct location.